# My Python Interpreter is not using the correct interpreter. I have reinstalled the Python extention and deactivated the Activate Integrated Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

This is my interpreter path ("C:\Users\smuss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"). Within this path are all my packages. The interpreter goes to another interpreter which is "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.exe" which doesnt contain all my packages.

```
def checkPythonInterpreter():

      print(sys.executable)
     
Output: C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.exe
```

Comment: Try running `C:\Users\smuss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe` directly; `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin` might have precedence in `%PATH%`, thus simply calling `python` may resolve to that.

Answer (score 0):

Pleasure to meet you.

Have you tried choose python interpreter in vscode?

1. Use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter"

[image]

2. Choose the correct interpreter which you want.

[image]